# Greatest common divisor Pascal (more than 2 values)

Tags: arrays, pascal, greatest-common-divisor

How to find GCD if there are more than 2 values in the array ?

I was thinking to find the smallest value, and try dividing every element from the array by it and if mod is not 0 then take away 1 from that value and start again.

But I only get 0 so that's the wrong way, any ideas ?

```
program GreatestCommonDivisor;
type mas = array[1..100] of integer;
var n : integer;
M : mas;
Rf : text;

procedure Skaityti;
 var i : integer;
 Df : text;
begin
Assign(Df,'duom1.txt');
Reset(Df);
Readln(Df,n);

for i := 1 to n do
    Read(Df,M[i]);
Close(Df);
end;
function GCD(M : array of integer): integer;
  var i,min : integer;
  begin
    min := M[1];
    for i := 1 to n do
     begin
        if min > M[i] then
            min := M[i];
     end;
        i := 1;
     repeat
        if M[i] mod min = 0 then
            GCD := min
        else
         begin
            min := min - 1 ;
            i := 0;
            continue;
         end;
         i := i + 1;
     until i = n;
  end;
 var min,i : integer;
 begin
   Skaityti;
Assign(Rf,'rez.txt');
for i := 1 to n do
Writeln(Rf,GCD(M),' ',min);

Close(Rf);

end.
```

Comment: Show your code, there is obvously something wong if you do not get at least 1 as gcd.

Comment: EDited it in to the question

Comment: Where's `M` coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your input is, but here is where I think you have the flaw in your reasoning:

First you try to find the smallest element as your potential gcd. Reasonable assumption, the gcd can not be larger than this of course. However, then you loop trough your list and if the assumed gcd does not divide evenly you reduce it by one and continue. This will not work.

```
Start = 10, 9, 8; min = 8; gcd is undefined (defaults to 0)
10 mod 8 is not 0, so min = 7
9 mod 7 is not 0, so min = 6
8 mode 6 is not 0, so min = 5
Done, gcd is now 0

Start = 10, 9, 8, 5, min = 5, gcd is undefined (defaults to 0)
10 mod 5 is 0, so gcd = 5
9 mod 5 is not 0, so min = 4
8 mod 4 is 0, so gcd = 4
5 mod 4 is not 0 so min = 3
Done, gcd is now 4
```

Here is a program which does calculate gcd (inefficiently)

```
Program ShowGCD(output);
type
   arr = array of integer;
var
   M: arr;

function GCD(M: arr ): integer;
   var i,min : integer;
begin
    min := M[0];
    for i := 1 to Length(M)-1 do begin
         if min > M[i] then
            min := M[i];
        end;
    i := 1;
    repeat
        if M[i] mod min = 0 then
            GCD := min
        else 
            begin
                min := min - 1;
                i := 0;
                continue;
            end;
        i := i + 1;
    until i = Length(M);
end;

begin
  M:=arr.Create(15, 45, 25);
  writeln('GCD: ', GCD(M));
end.
```

Comment: I get an error 200 "division by zero" I tried putting "If min = 0 then break; in the begining of the repeat loop, but the answer will just be 0 :/

Comment: What input do you use to get division by zero?

Comment: I'm using input from file, the first line is length of an array (4) and the second line is for  inputs which are 6,20,14,16

Comment: You are probably sending it the wrong values. Could it be that you send the method a larger array which contains zeros in the trailing elements? Running with `M:=arr.Create(6, 20, 14, 16);` gives `2` as expected while `M:=arr.Create(6, 20, 14, 16, 0);` gives "division by zero".

Comment: Either I don't really understand you or you don't understand me. You're saying that maybe I'm sending in bad array with 0 in it, but I already told you what array i'm sending. Or you meant something else ?

Comment: As I wrote ithe comment, testing with the array you mentioned gives the result 2. Obviously we are using different arrays. My is 1 based, could your be 0 based? If you add 'writeln(M[i]);' to the first loop, do you get each element printed as expected?

Comment: If I replace GCD function(to be able to compile) with procedure to write an array it will write the array I told earlier.

Comment: Edited it to the main.